# Hide rows which are empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have working code to hide empty rows between a set range (B13 to J45):

```vb
For i = 13 To 45
    If Cells(i, "B") & Cells(i, "C") & Cells(i, "D") & Cells(i, "E") & Cells(i, "F") & Cells(i, "G") _
    & Cells(i, "F") & Cells(i, "G") & Cells(i, "H") & Cells(i, "I") & Cells(i, "J") = "" Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

When I change the row values, I get

> Type mismatch/Run-time error '13' error

This is what I tried to run (the only difference is the row range i.e. 58 to 81):

```vb
For i = 58 To 81
    If Cells(i, "B") & Cells(i, "C") & Cells(i, "D") & Cells(i, "E") & Cells(i, "F") & Cells(i, "G") _
    & Cells(i, "F") & Cells(i, "G") & Cells(i, "H") & Cells(i, "I") & Cells(i, "J") = "" Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

1. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
2. Is there a smarter approach to doing this?

Comment: Most likely you've got error values in some of the cells. Try: `If Worksheetfunction.CountIf(Cells(i, "B").Resize(1, 9),"<>") = 0 Then`

Comment: Thanks for replying, so it runs but doesn't do anything. The rows have formulas in them perhaps that's why it doesn't remove them. Not sure how best to incorporate that due to this.

Comment: The rows to remove are generated based on a specific value inputted, so there's a way to remove the rows based on the position of the rows.I think this approach may be better given the way the sheet is set up currently.

Comment: Do the formulas return ""?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, visually it's blank but if i click on the cell its got a long formula written in it.

Comment: That would suggest that the formulas *are* returning "". When the formulas return an actual value, should it be a number or text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hide Rows

- Instead of `ActiveSheet`, you may rather want to use something like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Hide1()
    HideRows 13, 45
End Sub

Sub Hide2()
    HideRows 58, 61
End Sub

Sub HideRows( _
        ByVal FirstRow As Long, _
        ByVal LastRow As Long)
    Const ColsAddress As String = "B:J"
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.Columns(ColsAddress)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = crg.Columns.Count
    Dim trg As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        If Application.CountBlank(crg.Rows(i)) = cCount Then
            If trg Is Nothing Then
                Set trg = ws.Rows(i)
            Else
                Set trg = Union(trg, ws.Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not trg Is Nothing Then
        trg.Rows.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @VBasic2008, thanks for this it works perfectly. I'm attempting to run this sub within my main sub but it doesn't run. It only runs when I run each sub seperately. I.e. I tried to use Call Hide1 within my main sub but it does nothing. Do you know why?

Comment: Update: I got it to work but only after putting the command after "Application.ScreenUpdating = True". I'm assuming it doesn't like doing it if this is False.